# Apache Flink - Keep track of maximum

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

Suppose I have a datastream consisting of tuples `(t, q)` where `t` is the variable of interest.

Is there a distributed way of keeping track of the tuples with the maximum `t`? Just emit when the `t` is above the global maximum?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the state feature of Flink? (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/state.html)

I'm quite new to Flink myselfe but I think it provieds the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, but I am considered about the sharing of the state. It would mean that if the state is getting big, a lot of network traffic will be generated for maintaining the state. I am now looking into `coGroup`, maybe there is a possibility?

Comment: As far as I understand, state is always local to the TaskManager. But if you key your stream, the part of the stream with the same key always gets to the same TaskManager.
But I think this is not quite what you want to/can do with your data!?

Comment: No, I sadly have to join/cogroup them, so I need to maintain either a global state for that (which would not be efficient).